# mysqldump can't find 67 out of 87 tables in database

Tags: mysql

we are using software collections on CentOS 6 to allow a wordpress site to use mysql57.

This invocation terminates without reporting an error.

```
/opt/rh/rh-mysql57/root/usr/bin/mysqldump -u <user> -p pop_support wp_users --single-transaction --no-data  > table_wp_users_pop_support.sql
```

The database has 87 tables. Only 20 are output. For example, it does not find wp_users.

I have tried this using root, as shown, and as the user created for wordpress database admin. Output is the same in either case.

I checked the user grants. Both users have all grants on all tables.

What have I overlooked?

Comment: Is `pop_support` a database or a password? If password, there should be no space between `-p` and it, so `-ppop_support`.

Comment: Does <user> have permissions for all the databases?

Comment: "pop_support" is the name of the database. the <user> is the account that WordPress used to run install and updates. "Show grants for <user>" reports `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO <user>@localhost` and 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON pops_support.pops_support TO '<user>'@'localhost'`

Comment: One thing to add I assumed was not relevant, but just in case... The database has a mix of InnoDB and MyISAM tables. Not preferred, but that is the case.

Comment: The grants suggest that you have only privilege to read one table: `pops_support.pops_support`. The USAGE privilege only means your user can connect, not read any tables.

Comment: Thank you. I will revisit MySQL grant documentation.

Comment: Well, much to my surprise I discovered the server had two installs of mysql57, and with that two different databases of the same name. so there is some confusion in the utilities. I have sorted out how to get the data I need and will retire this server soon. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the server had two installs of mysql57, and with that two different databases of the same name. Hence the different results. Ugh.